# Creating a dictionary from a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary, data-science

[dataframe img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i9a7X.png)
I want to map the retail_store_id with the medicine name, by creating a dictionary where 53 i.e the retail_store_id is the key and the values will be the corresponding medicine name.

```
dict = { '53': ['PAN 40MG TAB', 'MOXIKIND CV 625MG TAB'.....]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have considered the below dataset as example

[image]

you can use the below code.

```
import os
import  pandas as pd

# create a empty dictionary
dict = {}

# read the data from the dataframe
df = pd.read_excel(r'C:\*********\Output.xlsx')

# iterate over the DF
for index in df.index:

    # initialize key vairiable with ID columns
    key = df['ID'][index]

    # if key alreadt exists the append the value which is in list format for else starting 
    # adding values into a list
    if key in dict:
        dict[key].append(df['Medicine Name'][index])
    else:    
        dict[key] = [df['Medicine Name'][index]]


print(dict)
```

Output Dictionary

```
{53: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'], 
54: ['G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K'], 
55: ['L', 'M']}
```